# String similarity Search in R

Tags: r, text-mining, text-analysis

I have a big list of Product Descriptions something like

```
Water bottles 1L
Water Can 1L
Aerated Drinks 1L
Chips Potato
Doritos Chips
Bread
Yogurt 300ML
Milk
```

Ofcourse the list is in Millions.

I am trying to create a search similarity. I want a search function which will Pick Similarity descriptions. If I search on Milk Products, it should bring Milk, Butter, Yogurt something like that.

For that I used `levenshteinSim` and run all the descriptions in Loop and compare with my search string. By the time it ran for all Million records it is taking long time. Is there any algorithm that will take data frame and string as input parameter and min score to get the values?

Comment: If you want to specifically use `levenshteinSim` simply replace `adist` with `levenshteinSim` in the second edit from my post below.  If you feel that the solution proposed is not answering the question, please add a comment addressing what specifically you want it to do rather than repeatedly re-editing your question.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty straight forward case for `grep`

```
grep("milk", searchDF[["description"]], ignore.case = TRUE)
```

EDIT:

Sorry didn't realize you were searching a list of dataframes rather than just one dataframe with all of the descriptions in one long string.

```
vapply(searchList, function(x) any(grepl("milk", x, ignore.case = TRUE)), 
       logical(1))
```

`vapply` will look through all the elements of your list in a vectorized fashion and speed things up.  `grepl` is like `grep`, but it returns a logical rather than an index.  `any` then checks all of the logicals returned by `grepl` to see if the search string `"milk"` was there.  The `logical(1)` at the end just indicates that the function will return a single logical value for each index of the `searchList`.  You could also use `sapply` and avoid having to put the `logical(1)` at the end, but `vapply` is generally safer since `sapply` will sometimes return an unexpected data type.

Edit 2:

I am not familiar with `levenshteinSim` but the function `adist` in `utils` also calculates the levenshtein distance.  If you want the minimum distance instead of just presence or absence in your list of strings you can use a similar strategy but with `adist`.

```
vapply(searchList, function(x) min(adist(x, "milk 1L", 
                                         ignore.case = TRUE)), 
       numeric(1))
```

Comment: That helps a lot.. I have another question, is there is way if I give levenshteinSim ('A','b'), this gives same values as levenshteinSim ('b','A'). Is it possible if the comparision is only one sided. Something like levenshteinSim ('Juice Mixer', 'Pansonic Mixer for Juice') should give 100% match.. a one way match, should not give 100% with this comparision levenshteinSim ( 'Pansonic Mixer for Juice', 'Juice Mixer')

Comment: You would need to be more specific for your scoring criterion as you are no longer calculating the Levenshtein distance.  For instance, should `newDistanceFunction("cinema", "iceman")` return 100% since all the letters in "cinema" are in "iceman"?  If it is only for whole words, how do you want it to deal with partial matches?  Should `newDistanceFunction("Milk Machine", "Milking Machine")` be 100% or some smaller value? How about `newDistanceFunction("Milking Machine", "Milk Machine")`?